# Not able to access a value returned by function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using a class

```
public partial class CashFlowIndicator:IEnumerable
{
    public static void getCashFlowChartValues(int userid)
    {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> chartValues=new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
            chartValues = cashFlowChart(userid);
    }    

    public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> cashFlowChart(int userid)
    {
              //.............................
              //..................................
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> cashFlowItems = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            cashFlowItems.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(a, b));
            cashFlowItems.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(c, d));
           //.....................    

            return cashFlowItems;
     }    
}
```

The problem is while calling the function cashFlowChart,  the variable "chartValues" is not getting assigned by the value returned.....

is there any solution?

Comment: Why are you initializing `chartValues` to a value you're then not using anyway? And does your `getCashFlowChartValues` method *really* stop after calling `cashFlowChart`? If so, what's the point of it? Basically we need more context - the code you've got at the moment doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JonSkeet No i have to pass the values returned.But before that i need to get the values right.Am in the midst of developing the function

Comment: The first time you set `chartValues` is redundant, as you're assigning a new value in the next line. Maybe something is happening where you cut away he code in `cashFlowChart` because that part of the code seems fine.

Comment: @Anjana: So how are you seeing that the value isn't being assigned the value returned? It really *will* be. I suspect you're diagnosing this incorrectly.

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick Its already been mentioned  in the code here

Comment: @Anjana Yes,I saw it, just removed my comment

Comment: (I'd also strongly recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions, which use PascalCase for methods.) Basically your code really won't behave how you're describing it, and you haven't explained how you've come to the conclusion you have - please provide a short but *complete* program (ideally a short console app) which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: eventhough your code is not clean,its still ok and a object address should be assigned.how are you checking this.

Comment: @JonSkeet i have included all the lines which can describe the problem well. There is no use of including the whole logic over here to feel crowded .

Comment: @Anjana In that case it should work. Are you sure you are inspecting the value after is has been assigned?
And if this is all your code, nothing is being done with the `chartValues` variable. Is it accidentally hiding a field with the same name in the class and are you then inspecting that hidden (unchanged) field afterwards?

Comment: @Anjana: I didn't say you needed to include everything. I said you needed to include enough to demonstrate the problem - ideally in a short but complete program we can run ourselves. You *still* haven't explained how you've diagnosed this, i.e. what makes you think that the variable doesn't have the right value. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the method name - "getCashFlowChartValues", and return type - "void", here is my guess -

you need to move the definition of "chartValues" outside the methods and make it 'static' (as shown below) :

```
public class CashFlowIndicator :IEnumerable
{

    static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> chartValues;  // has been moved here from getCashFlowChartValues

    public static void getCashFlowChartValues(int userid)
    {
            //List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> chartValues=new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
            chartValues = cashFlowChart(userid);
    }    

    public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> cashFlowChart(int userid)
    {
            //.............................
            //..................................
            var cashFlowItems = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            cashFlowItems.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(a, b));
            cashFlowItems.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(c, d));
        //.....................    

            return cashFlowItems;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are creating two objects, once in the `getCashFlowChartValues` methode at the line:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> chartValues=
                new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
```

and once in the methode `cashFlowChart` at line:

```
 List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> cashFlowItems = 
                new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

try to call the subfinction directly like:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> chartValues = cashFlowChart (userid);
```

Im not sure this will solve your problem but its much cleaner.

UPDATE:

I just tested the following code and its working for me, even in the original version when both objects ceated its working for me, and returnes the expected output, i would just set a breakpoint to take a deeper look, guess you will discover its working. Maby according to other lines in code your not getting the expected output:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> s in getCashFlowChartValues())
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(s.Key + s.Value);
            }
            System.Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> getCashFlowChartValues()
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> chartValues = cashFlowChart(5);
            return chartValues;
        }

        public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> cashFlowChart(int userid)
        {
            //.............................
            //..................................
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> cashFlowItems = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            cashFlowItems.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a", "b"));
            cashFlowItems.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("c", "d"));
            //.....................    

            return cashFlowItems;
        }
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the problem - it's basically the same comment that René Wolferink and I already made, but *as* comments...

Comment: Yes, you did - that doesn't make it any more suitable to be added as an answer.